# Logging for IBM MQ JCA Resource Adapter

Tags: jboss, ibm-mq

In versions 6 and 7 of IBM MQ, I could configure logging for the IBM MQ JCA resource adapter in JBoss as follows:

```
    <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:5.0">
        <resource-adapters>
            <resource-adapter id="wmq.jmsra.rar" statistics-enabled="true">
                <archive>
                    wmq.jmsra.rar
                </archive>
                <config-property name="logWriterEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceEnabled">
                    true
                </config-property>
                <config-property name="traceLevel">
                    6
                </config-property>
```

This configuration is described in the IBM MQ documentation.  In versions 8 and 9 of IBM MQ, the documentation states that the same configuration still applies.  I have not been able to get it to work.

Furthermore, I can set system properties in JBoss:

```
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.status" value="ON"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.level" value="10"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.append" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.startup" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.maxBytes" value="-1"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.limit" value="2097152"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.count" value="1"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.standalone" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.errorStream" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/wmq-trace-error.log"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.trace.outputName" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/wmq-trace.log"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.outputName" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/wmq.log"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.status" value="ON"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.maxBytes" value="-1"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.limit" value="2097152"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.count" value="1"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.log.append" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.ibm.msg.client.commonservices.ffst.suppress" value="-1"/>
```

and I can get logging from the IBM MQ JCA.  However, logging at traceLevel 6 does not produce any output.  Only traceLevel 8 and 10 (very verbose) produce logging.

Comment: There have been some fixes related to java/jms tracing,  are you using the latest 8.0.0.11, 9.0.0.5, and 9.1.0.1 for the observations you made?

Comment: I know that I have tried 9.1.0.1. I'll see if I can find the 8.0.0.11 java client.

Comment: No luck with the MQ 8.0.0.11 JCA.  The properties for the JCA are ignored, and no output for traceLevel 6 logging when using the common services properties.

Comment: Maybe: 
IV91716: Issues with IBM MQ Classes for Java trace

Comment: I think that would be fixed in 8.0.0.11 because a follow on APAR to the one you mentioned is fixed in 8.0.0.11.  I can't get to the page for IV91716 right now to see.

Comment: The 8.0.0.11 that I tried is build 8.0.0.11-p800-011-181212.1.  Which APAR, please?